# Google Android speech capture timeout

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-speech-api

Just a quick question about the Google speech capture inbuilt on most Android devices (not the cloud service) - see the attached image. Is there any way, either programatically or via the settings, to control how long it waits until it asks you to try again? The 'complete silence' fields in the RecognizerIntent don't seem to make any difference. On certain devices it times out very quickly and the user doesn't have enough time to start speaking.

This is the code in my test app:

```
 public void StartSpeechToText(ISpeechResultCallback callback)
    {

        string rec = global::Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureMicrophone;
        if (rec == "android.hardware.microphone")
        {
            MainActivity activity = MainActivity.CurrentActivity;
            activity.Callback = callback;

            var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);

            //var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionVoiceSearchHandsFree);

            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);

            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, "Speak now");

            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);

            activity.StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);


        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your code looks alright, I think you just need to remove 'ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis' That states that the minimum length of an utterance must be 15 seconds long, anything shorter and you'll get the try again prompt.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt it didn't make any difference when I did that, unfortunately.